# Javascript regexp match doesn't work

Tags: javascript, regex

```
var code = '{html}here is html code{/html}{css}here is css code{/css}';
var preg = code.match(new RegExp(/\{.*?\}(.*?)\{\/.*?\}/g));
console.log(preg[1][0]);
```

Result: {.

How to output "here is html code" and "here is css code"?

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cqr3K/

Comment: check out my edited answer, which uses your **own** regex!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way to get all submatches.

```
var code = '{html}here is html code{/html}{css}here is css code{/css}';
var re   = /[^}]+(?=\{)/g;
var match;

while (match = re.exec(code)) {
   console.log(match[0]);
}
```

Output

```
here is html code
here is css code
```

Comment: thank you. But I seriosly don't understand why /\{.*?\}(.*?)\{\/.*?\}/g doesn't work? :O

Comment: Well with `\{.*?\}(.*?)\{\/.*?\}` your match is captured in capture group #1, See [live demo](http://regex101.com/r/cY8wC4)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
var code = '{html}here is html code{/html}{css}here is css code{/css}';
var preg = code.replace(/\{.*?\}(.*?)\{\/.*?\}/g, function (match,group) {
    console.log(group);
    return "";
});
```

Comment: @owl, how did you try?

Comment: Your second suggestion doesn't work. I tried it myself as well. :) First one is better.

Comment: @sshashank124, it didn't work because the js code was wrong. see my edit.

Comment: @AmitJoki, thank you, but why result is:

}here is html code{
}{css}here is css code{

Comment: @owl wait for some minutes

Answer (score 0):

You can do that as follows:

`/\}(.*?)\{/g`

The first captured group `$1` is what you want. It will contain `here is html code` and `here is css code`

Demo: http://regex101.com/r/yC7lD7